# I get this error when I try to access file from iis of another system

Tags: c#, iis

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access files over network by IIS, however to do that, in network share you will need to add IUSER_ , IWAM_ or ASPNET user permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but neither giving access to Network Service, nor to IUSR helped me. I was trying to deploy an ASP.Net 4.0 web application with Forms Authentication on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008. What solved the problem was providing read and script permissions to the handlers, which can be accomplished by opening Handler Mappings and then selecting "Edit Feature Permissions" from the right menu.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you don't have permission...  If this is unexpected, provide some more information and we can help.

Comment: Dude, this is what comments are for, this "answer" is a downvote maginet, I'd remove if I were you (just some friendly advice, I not telling you what to do)

Comment: It is kinda funny though - it's not like the error isn't informative :)